# Is the restriction on this system necessary?

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations, roots, physics, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to solve the following non-linear system:

$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}+s(t_2-t_1) = \sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2}$

$\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}+s(t_3-t_2) = \sqrt{(x-x_3)^2 + (y-y_3)^2}$

$\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}+s(t_1-t_3) = \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}$

For the unknowns, $x$ and $y$. The system is the solution to a localization problem, where, given the coordinates $[x_i,y_i]$ of three parties, the time at which each party "saw" some signal ($t_i$), and the speed of that signal, $s$, the coordinates of the source are given by $[x,y]$. Here, we assume that the coordinates and the source are coplanar.

I read somewhere that, to write the system above, one must have that $t_1 < t_2 < t_3$. Is this the case? And if so, why?

My goal right now is to solve for $[x,y]$ algorithmically, by setting the equations equal to 0 and plugging them into a root-finder. I want to do this hundreds of times, so as to localize hundreds of events, and in many cases this constraint is not met. Can I still simply plug the values in?

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions on this problem. Your previous question inspired me to construct a solution to this localization problem in both two and three dimensions using MATLAB. The solver I used in each case was the built in "solve" command which worked beautifully.

Here is the other post I referenced.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849210/system-of-equations-always-produces-approximately-the-same-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction that $t_1 < t_2 < t_3$ need not be met to solve these equations and get a meaningful answer. If the restriction were necessary, this still wouldn't be a problem from an "algorithmic" point of view. We could always just rename the observers in an order aligned with $t_1 < t_2 < t_3 \; .$ In other words we would arbitrarily state that the observer that saw the signal first has coordinates $(x_1, y_1) \;$ and continue on from there.

Once again though, the equations can be solved no matter which numbered observer sees the signal first. This is true in 3d as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Much appreciated. I'm using the CERN ROOT <root.cern.ch> implementation of the GNU MultiRootFinder in my code. I supplied the first 2 equations to the solver, and set the initial point as  the center of the circle circumscribed by the 3 parties (I should point out that I know the source to be outside of that circle), and I set the max iterations to 10,000. I get an error message, "the solver is not making any progress". I'm wondering, what mistake have I made here? Thanks again for the help, and apologies for the likely very basic questions (this is very new to me).

Comment: To add onto my previous comment, I've tried playing with the # if iterations. When I decrease the # of iterations, I get a new error "exceeded max iterations, reached tolerance is not sufficient", where my tolerance is set to the default value of 1E-06. If you could, what tolerance/# of iterations were used with your implementation (it will vary, of course, from algorithm to algorithm, but maybe it would be a helpful starting point)?

Comment: @KeithMadison  I was using MATLAB's symbolic solver. I just reimplemented it using the numeric solver "fsolve". I used Levenberg-Marquardt with 1500 max iterations and $\varepsilon = 10^{-6} \; .$ The initial point was set fairly randomly and the source was placed outside the triangle spanned by the three observers. Both the symbolic and numerical solvers do great work and reproduce the original point to a high degree of accuracy. I'll look into this problem a bit more when I have more time. I think there are "good" and "bad" choices for where the observers are placed.